# How to specify home directory when creating a user in linux?

Tags: linux, useradd

I want to specify the home directory when creating a user, currently i'm using centos 6.7

Is it possible?

Comment: Please learn how to find out this stuff yourself. `man` pages exist, including `man useradd`.

Comment: Sorry for the bad question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this to simply add a user:

> useradd -m -d /home/newuser newuser

Or this to add a user by asking you some questions

> adduser --home /home/newuser2 newuser2

Comment: FYI, those commands were tested on Ubuntu.